# Have org-mode continue a numbered list rather than restarting

Tags: org-mode

Any way to have org-mode continue a numbered list rather than restarting?

Here is the situation. You make a list like:

> Sometimes you can restart the display by doing something like this:
>
> 1. Hit Ctrl-Alt-F1 to open up a terminal.
> 2. Enter the following two commands:
>
> #+BEGIN_SRC bash
>
> > export DISPLAY=:0.0
> >
> > cinnamon --replace
>
> #+END_SRC
>
> \3. Then hit Ctrl-Alt-F8 to go back to the window manager.

Both the markdown editor and org-mode want the #3 to be #1, restarting the list after the code block.

SOLUTION below. Now it looks perfect. Here's a tip for recovering when Cinnamon locks up in Ubuntu 12.04 or Mint 13.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try indenting the #+BEGIN_SRC block, so it "looks" like it's a child of item number 2 instead of a top-level item. Does doing that fix your problem?

Like this:

```
 1. Hit Ctrl-Alt-F1 to open up a terminal.
 2. Enter the following two commands:

    #+BEGIN_SRC bash

        export DISPLAY=:0.0

        cinnamon --replace

    #+END_SRC

 3. Then hit Ctrl-Alt-F8 to go back to the window manager
```

Comment: on my end it puts bullet

Answer (score 36):

You can tell org-mode what the label of each item should be, so you can make the next list start with the number following the last one from the previous list.  The [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html) for version 8.2.5h says (with boldness added by me):

> Ordered list items start with a numeral followed by either a period or a right parenthesis, such as ‘1.’ or ‘1)’. **If you want a list to start with a different value (e.g., 20), start the text of the item with [@20].** Those constructs can be used in any item of the list in order to enforce a particular numbering.

Using this, you can indent the text between the two lists any way you like, but there is no automatic updating of the numbering when the previous list changes.

Example:

```
Here comes a multi-part list.

1. Item the first.
2. Item the second.

Here is some intermediate text.

3. [@3] Item the third.
4. Item the fourth.
```

Comment: Now, with an example, I'm free to read the documentation as it's written, and not as I think it is written: I read it 5 times and completely missed "start the **text of the item**", and just kept trying `[@3]. My text...`. :(

Comment: Thank you for the example! I also misread the text repeatedly!

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer, as it is more general than the accepted one.

Comment: @Thriveth, I agree. That said, by now (Feb 2022), this answer has received enough upvotes that it exceeds the votes score of the accepted one, and as a result it is positioned immediately after the question. I wouldn't even have looked past this one had it not been for your comment. Given that, maybe one way to look at things is that "accepted" status, with its green check mark, really means nothing more than that it was the answer that the OP...well, accepted. That is, it should not be taken as any kind of mark of "bestness". I'm certainly going to look at it that way from here on.

Answer (score 8):

[The org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Plain-lists) [describes precisely](http://orgmode.org/org.html#fnd-18) what terminates lists. Quoting from it :

> A list ends whenever every item has ended, which means before any line less or equally indented than items at top level. It also ends before two blank lines¹.

```
¹ See also org-empty-line-terminates-plain-lists.
```

As Daniel [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12985152/1449460), indenting all in between `2.` and `3.` should solve your problem.